# So nginx always walk through the same set of filters for each request?

Tags: filter, nginx

```
&ngx_http_write_filter_module,
&ngx_http_header_filter_module,
&ngx_http_chunked_filter_module,
&ngx_http_range_header_filter_module,
&ngx_http_gzip_filter_module,
&ngx_http_postpone_filter_module,
&ngx_http_ssi_filter_module,
&ngx_http_charset_filter_module,
&ngx_http_userid_filter_module,
&ngx_http_headers_filter_module,
&ngx_http_copy_filter_module,
&ngx_http_range_body_filter_module,
&ngx_http_not_modified_filter_module,
```

I know that nginx modules are compiled into nginx binary,not dynamic linked.

Does that mean that all the above 13 filters will execute on each request no matter what?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That is true. For example, following is the init function from gzip module. But don't worry about it much because most filters will bail out early if they are not applicable.

```
static ngx_int_t ngx_http_gzip_filter_init(ngx_conf_t *cf)
{
    ngx_http_next_header_filter = ngx_http_top_header_filter;
    ngx_http_top_header_filter = ngx_http_gzip_header_filter;

    ngx_http_next_body_filter = ngx_http_top_body_filter;
    ngx_http_top_body_filter = ngx_http_gzip_body_filter;

    return NGX_OK;
}
```